# Wordpress Docker behind Nginx Proxy Manager, no SSL

Tags: wordpress, docker, ssl, npm, containers

I have created a docker stack with WordPress, MySQL and phpMyAdmin. The docker system is still an Nginx proxy manager that listens to the domain and forwards to the stack. With NPM I also got a Let's Encrypt certificate.
Settings in WordPress: I only specified HTTP and I can get into wp-admin via HTTP and the dashboard looks good. However, when I click on anything, it redirects to HTTPS and the design doesn't load properly anymore.
The page itself reports ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.
Cookies were deleted but has not helped. Have you maybe a tip?

Best Greetings

I tried in the settings of WordPress to switch the URL to HTTPS but did not bring any change.
I also tried the WordPress help on how to use a reverse proxy.
https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/administration-over-ssl/#using-a-reverse-proxy

Then the dashboard is accessible via HTTP and looks right, but all links go back to HTTPS and the design is broken. The website itself is only partially loaded correctly because a lot is loaded via HTTP, so the design is broken too.

Answer (score 0):

This entry in wp-config.php helped:
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).